# « Partir en vrille » : s'emballer vers le bas ?

Tags: vocabulaire, locutions, origine-ou-raison, transports, connotation

On a la locution verbale [*partir en vrille*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/partir_en_vrille) pour décrire entre autres « [...] une situation qui dégénère brutalement, parfois sans raison valable » (Wiktionnaire). Je me demande si l'origine c'est le domaine de l'aviation avec la [*vrille*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vrille) pour le « mouvement, figure d'acrobatie d'un avion qui descend en tournant sur lui-même » (TLFi). C'est que cette locution n'est pas employée à mon connaissance dans mon environnement linguistique et je n'ai pas compris spontanément l'idée de mouvement vers le bas ni donc l'expression (je n'y ai compris que « [capoter](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/capoter) », une « vrille » sans le mouvement vertical, essentiellement pour *s'emballer*).

Peut-on confirmer et préciser ; est-ce différent de *s'[emballer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/emballer)* ?

Answer (score 1):

En ce qui a trait à la première partie de la question, oui essentiellement :

> Par analogie, il [le mot vrille] se dit il se dit de ce qui a la forme d'une hélice
>   (1839), spécialement du mouvement d'un avion qui tombe en tournant sur
>   lui-même (1916-1918) [...] La chute en vrille (involontaire) d'un
>   avion a suscité la locution figurée *partir en vrille* « devenir hors de
>   contrôle » et « s'effondrer » (années 1990).
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. Rey, chez
>   Robert, 2011 ]